# Spring Data. Hibernate. Restrict result in joined table when one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 table.
i want to find last action than was made by user, also add possibility to send as parameter max date for this action

```
create table user(
 id int,
 name char(5)
);

create table action(
 id int,
 user_id int,
 action char(5),
 rep_date date
);
```

in sql it will be like that

```
select t1.*, t2* from user t1
left join action t2 on (t1.id = t2.user_id)
join (select t3.user_id, max(t3.rep_date) as max_date
from action t3
group by t3.user_id) t4 on (t2.user_id=t4.user_id and t2.rep_date=t4.max_date)
```

i create entity class in User is have
  @OneToMany on List

in repository

```
 @Repository
    public interface StudyMatherialRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
        @Query(value="select distinct u from User u left join fetch sm.action a1 join (select a2.user_id, max(a2.rep_date) max_date from  sm.history a2
group by a2.user_id) a3 on (a1.user_id = a2.user_id and a1.rep_date= a2.max_date)
")
        public List<StudyMaterial> findAllwithNative();
    }
```

i got
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token
and cant figure how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier to accomplish this by coming from the `UserAction` entity, which could have a `@ManyToOne` relationship to `User`, allowing us to join-fetch it:

```
SELECT a
FROM UserAction a
JOIN FETCH a.user u
WHERE a.id IN (
  SELECT a_.id
    FROM UserAction a_
   GROUP BY a_.user
   HAVING MAX( a_.repDate )
)
```